# A noob question about sudo/pseudo

Tags: linux, sudo

What command is the 'pseudo' user able to run without entering a password?

Comment: Hello an welcome to the Unix and Linux stack exchange site! Your post is not very clear. When you mean "pseudo" user do you mean a user that is not really a user or a user in the sudoers/wheel group able to run commands with `sudo` and elevate their permissions to root level? This question is also very broad as one could set up a passwordless `sudo`....

Comment: pseudo meaning fake, and sudo meaning superuser do or set user do, are different words, and have no connection.

Comment: I'm wondering whether "pseudo" is the way that you have heard "sudo" been pronounced? In that case, please update the question to replace all mentioning of "pseudo" with "sudo".

Answer (score 1):

The commands that `sudo` can run with-out password, is determined by the configuration in `/etc/sudoers`. While pseudo means fake (A totally different thing).

Type `man sudoers`, for more information.